# Is it possible to call a function from a header file in that same header file? (C99)

Tags: c, function, file, c99, forward-declaration

I want to know before I dump time into what might not be a viable coding method.

If I make a header file with a function somewhere in it, `double fill(char *howtofill)`, can I then call the function inside the header file?

Comment: Header files don't usually contain function definitions but just the function declarations, so there wouldn't normally be any function calls in a header file. Instead, the function calls would occur in the function definitions in the corresponding code file, and yes, the functions are allowed to call each other. Have you created a multi-file project before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in C, header files are used to declare function prototypes, which will then be included in proper C files (by the compiler). These prototypes make the C file code aware about functions, hardcoded in other C files, not in headers.

If you think you need to put code in a .h file, you probably have to think again about your program architecture.

Good to know: all your .h file content will be "copy-pasted" to the C file in place of the `#include "file.h"` directive.
After the first step of the compiler (called *preprocessing*), your code will end in a single big file.

If this does not help you, can you tell us more about your problem ?

Comment: The overall program calculates properties for a bunch of constituent chemicals mixed in solution. In my header file, I declare a struct called t_member, which contains the name, chemical formula, and molecular weight of a chemical. the members are sub-structs of the solution structure, which houses the members and some other variables like temperature. Since water and ethanol will always be in the solution, I want to fill the t_member for those members from the get-go.

Comment: Why not to use a function that populates the structure with t_member water and t_member ethanol. You could call it each time you create a structure, to pre-populate it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I wasn't aware that the header file only writes prototypes (I thought the function body went in the .h as well). Now that I know, I'm putting the filler function in a separate c function file.